# FAQ: Linguistic Terminology

Tags: discussion, faq

I have problems understanding some answers/questions because the terminology being used is too technical. Where can I find out what is the meaning of a particular term?

[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful sites that you can use to search Linguistic terms are (in alphabetical order):

- [Glossary of Linguistic terms](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOflinguisticTerms/)
- [Glottopedia](http://www.glottopedia.de/index.php/Main_Page)
- [IPA](http://www.langsci.ucl.ac.uk/ipa/)
- [Lexicon of Linguistics](http://www2.let.uu.nl/uil-ots/lexicon/)
- [The Online Dictionary of Language Terminology](http://www.odlt.org/)
- [A Glossary of Historical Linguistics](http://www.szabir.com/data/files/File/167/A-Glossary-of-Historical-Linguistics.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

For a description of the abbreviations used in glosses, see the [Leipzig Glossing Rules](http://grammar.ucsd.edu/courses/lign120/leipziggloss.pdf).